# Why so huge difference between data quantity if a number of bits and bytes just doubled?

Tags: java

`Byte` has `8 bits` value what is = `1 byte` and It is can hold values from `- 128` to `127` and `short` has `16 bits` of what is = `2 bytes` can hold `- 32768` to `32767`.

Why so huge difference between data quantity if a number of bits and bytes just doubled? We need to have - 254 to 253 not 32 thousand with something. Why do we have a number in 258 times more, not just twice?

Why do we have the so huge difference between data memory reservation in particular data types? I mean, why bits doubled but data actually growing like geometrically not doubled? Is that just because it is useful? Or something?

Thanks

Comment: Multiply 2 by 2 the number of bits. That is why. 2^16 is 65536 (32768 if you include the sign).

Comment: Thanks!!! Now I am less confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8 bits can hold 2<sup>8</sup> values (256)

16 bits can hold 2<sup>16</sup> values (65536)

> Is that just because it is useful?

No, this is because of math

Comment: I approciated your answer!